# Rain caused the core of patio door to expand. Can this door be fixed and how do I prevent this in the future?

Tags: doors, patio, water-damage

I have this door to our patio, which seems to have a cheap core (i.e., it's not solid wood). It's been raining a lot lately, and I think the core of the door somehow absorbed a lot of water. The core has expanded, and I can barely open/close the door anymore. This door was installed only three years ago, so I'd like to not have to shell out a lot of money again to replace it if I can avoid it. Can I fix this door, for example by sanding off the expanded bottom? And what do I need to do so this doesn't happen again? Thank you.

[image: View of the door from the inside]

[image: View of the bottom of the door from the outside]

Comment: If the inside core is a material that will dry out and shrink again(low chance), then best way is to bring it inside in a warm dry area to dry out(not likely for an outside door).  Once dry can re glue  and clamp back together.  Reseal all seams.

Comment: I wonder if the pet door has something to do with the problem.

Comment: Is that an "L" or "U" shaped plastic cap over the bottom of the core? If so that is a strong indicator that the water got inside, like the pet door, not simply through the bottom...

Comment: That door is in bad shape for such a new door. A temporary fix would be to force the bottom piece back up flush with the side pieces and then countersink some wood screws through the side pieces into the bottom on both edges to hold the bottom in place.